# A ball dropped onto a rotating wheel of various frequencies experiment issues

Tags: kinematics, time, frequency, angular-velocity

I'm doing a experiment to find the relationship between the frequency of the rotating wheel and the horizontal distance travelled by the ball dropped onto it. I am manipulating the frequency of the spinning wheel and the responding variable would be the horizontal distance travelled by the ball. Assuming no friction, the formula I devised was $\vec d_x=2\pi rft$. To make a meaningful relationship equation, I would need to calculate the slope which would only be possible if the graph was linear. However, I was confused about whether the time value would affect this since the time would be different for each frequency. Is it allowed if I keep the time value a constant? Or is there a better formula/way to use? Thanks.